# LibGDX - Ads on iOS

Tags: libgdx, googleads-mobile-unity

I'm making an application using LibGDX and RoboVM, and I'm stucked in a problem with the Google Mobile Ads Framework.
I've search everywhere but nothing resolved my error.

If I declare this framework in the ***robovm.xml*** like this

```
  <frameworkPaths>
    <path>libs</path>
  </frameworkPaths>
  <frameworks>
    <framework>UIKit</framework>
    <framework>OpenGLES</framework>
    <framework>QuartzCore</framework>
    <framework>CoreGraphics</framework>
    <framework>OpenAL</framework>
    <framework>AudioToolbox</framework>
    <framework>AVFoundation</framework>
    <framework>GoogleMobileAds</framework>
  </frameworks>
```

When I'm going to create the IPA it gives me this error.

How can I solve this??

```
[ERROR] Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
[ERROR]   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GLKView", referenced from:
[ERROR]       objc-class-ref in GoogleMobileAds(flat-armv7)
[ERROR]   "_kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey", referenced from:
[ERROR]       l5704 in GoogleMobileAds(flat-armv7)
[ERROR]      (maybe you meant: _str_kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey_00)
[ERROR]   "_kCVImageBufferYCbCrMatrix_ITU_R_601_4", referenced from:
[ERROR]       l4155 in GoogleMobileAds(flat-armv7)
[ERROR]   "_GLKMatrix4Identity", referenced from:
[ERROR]       l4149 in GoogleMobileAds(flat-armv7)
[ERROR]       l4160 in GoogleMobileAds(flat-armv7)
[ERROR]      (maybe you meant: _str_GLKMatrix4Identity_00)
[ERROR]   "_CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget", referenced from:
[ERROR]       l4158 in GoogleMobileAds(flat-armv7)
[ERROR]   "_CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate", referenced from:
[ERROR]       l4157 in GoogleMobileAds(flat-armv7)
[ERROR]   "_CFHostStartInfoResolution", referenced from:
[ERROR]       l3806 in GoogleMobileAds(flat-armv7)
[ERROR]   "_CVBufferGetAttachment", referenced from:
[ERROR]       l4155 in GoogleMobileAds(flat-armv7)
[ERROR]      (maybe you meant: _str_CVBufferGetAttachment_00, _str_CVBufferGetAttachments_00 )
[ERROR]   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CMMotionManager", referenced from:
[ERROR]       objc-class-ref in GoogleMobileAds(flat-armv7)
[ERROR]   "_kCVImageBufferYCbCrMatrixKey", referenced from:
[ERROR]       l4155 in GoogleMobileAds(flat-armv7)
[ERROR]      (maybe you meant: _str_kCVImageBufferYCbCrMatrixKey_00)
[ERROR]   "_CVPixelBufferGetWidth", referenced from:
[ERROR]       l4155 in GoogleMobileAds(flat-armv7)
[ERROR]      (maybe you meant: _str_CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane_00, _str_CVPixelBufferGetWidth_00 )
[ERROR]   "_CFHostCreateWithName", referenced from:
[ERROR]       l3806 in GoogleMobileAds(flat-armv7)
[ERROR]   "_SecCertificateCreateWithData", referenced from:
[ERROR]       l778 in GoogleMobileAds(flat-armv7)
[ERROR]   "_CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage", referenced from:
[ERROR]       l4158 in GoogleMobileAds(flat-armv7)
[ERROR]   "_CVOpenGLESTextureGetName", referenced from:
[ERROR]       l4158 in GoogleMobileAds(flat-armv7)
[ERROR]   "_SecTrustCreateWithCertificates", referenced from:
[ERROR]       l778 in GoogleMobileAds(flat-armv7)
[ERROR]   "_CVOpenGLESTextureCacheFlush", referenced from:
[ERROR]       l4156 in GoogleMobileAds(flat-armv7)
[ERROR]   "_CVPixelBufferGetHeight", referenced from:
[ERROR]       l4155 in GoogleMobileAds(flat-armv7)
[ERROR]      (maybe you meant: _str_CVPixelBufferGetHeight_00, _str_CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane_00 )
[ERROR]   "_CFHostGetAddressing", referenced from:
[ERROR]       l3806 in GoogleMobileAds(flat-armv7)
[ERROR]   "_SecKeyRawVerify", referenced from:
[ERROR]       l780 in GoogleMobileAds(flat-armv7)
[ERROR]   "_SecTrustEvaluate", referenced from:
[ERROR]       l778 in GoogleMobileAds(flat-armv7)
[ERROR]   "_SecTrustCopyPublicKey", referenced from:
[ERROR]       l778 in GoogleMobileAds(flat-armv7)
[ERROR] ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
[ERROR] clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I need this answer as weel